# Prove that if $m,n $ are natural and $m>n $ then $m-n$ is natural

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I'm defining real numbers from the field axioms plus 2 axioms stating that:

1. The set of positive real numbers is closed for addition and multiplication.
2. All real numbers except zero either belong to the set of positive real numbers or are symmetrics of the real numbers and no positive real is equal to its symmetric.

(Also the supremum axiom but I'm required not to use it yet.)

The definition I'm given for the set of natural numbers is the intersection of all inductive subsets of real numbers which contain $0$. (Inductive meaning that if $x$ belongs to that set then so does $x+1$).

I havent yet proved the well ordering theorem. From the definition, it was easy to prove that induction can be used to prove statements for all natural, and also very simple to prove that the naturals are closed for multiplication and addition. However whatever I do I cant prove the following:

$$\forall m,n \in N : m>n \implies m-n \in N$$

My attempt was the following:

Induction basis: $\forall m \in N: m>0 \implies m-0 \in N$
Which is obvious.

Induction hypothesis: $\forall m \in N: m>k \implies m-k \in N$

So we have 3 possibilities: either $k+1>m$ or $k+1=n$ or $k+1<m$. The first two evidently mean the condition holds for k+1. But if $k+1<m$ then I have to prove that $m-k-1 \in N$. I have no idea how  to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. As a clarification: How to you define the "$>$" relation? When I studied this I recall defining that there should be a set $p$ (which would actually be the positive numbers) such that $a>b$ implies $a-b\in p$.

Comment: @Mefitico yes, $a<b \iff (b-a$ is positive $)$.

Comment: Then how do you define the integers? Don't use something around the lines of $(\forall a\in \mathbb N) \rightarrow \exists (-a) \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a+(-a)=0$? Wouldn't something along these lines  allow stating that $(m-n)>0 \in \mathbb Z \Rightarrow (m-n)\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: But then I run into similar problems. I have $Z = \{x: x \in N \lor (-x) \in N \}$. But how do I prove that $m-n \in Z$ when I do not know if either $m-n$ or $n-m $ are in $N$ ?

Comment: Assume $(m-n)>0 \notin \mathbb Z$ Then $(m-n) \notin \mathbb N$ and $-(m-n) \notin \mathbb N$, can you reach a contradiction?

Comment: I can't, nothing I tried reached any contradiction.

Comment: @HortaBe I fixed a typo: you had “real” instead of the intended “natural”.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's nice that you attacked this problem using induction, but it's better to do it for $m$.
You should first fix $n$, for $m = n+1$ we have $(m-n) \in \Bbb{N}$, clearly.
Now, let $m\in \Bbb{N_{\ge n+1}}: m-n \in \Bbb{N}$.

We have $m-n \in \Bbb{N}$
Therefore $S(m-n)=m+1-n \in \Bbb{N}$
With S the successor function
We have then $$\forall m\in \Bbb{N_{\ge n+1}},m-n \in \Bbb{N}$$
So $$\forall n\in \Bbb{N},\forall m\in \Bbb{N}, m>n\implies m-n \in \Bbb{N}$$

Comment: If I understood that well, it seems that you use the "fact" that there's no natural between $n$ and $n+1$. However I have not proved that yet. So it seems to me like you only proved it for $m > n+1$  and for $m=n+1$, which I dont know yet that is equivalent to for $m>n$

Comment: @HortaBe Your property is actually true when replacing $m>n$ by $m\geq n$. Then you can start at $m=n$ to avoid your issue. But in fact, depending on what are your axiom exactly, you would still need to know that there is no natural strictly between $n$ and $n+1$ to use the induction principle (otherwise, what is keeping you to apply the induction principle with the set $\mathbb N\cup(\mathbb N+1/2)$, which is inductive from your definition). Now proving that there is no natural between $n$ and $n+1$ should not be too hard using the minimality of $\mathbb N$ among inductive sets.

Comment: @Pece well that's precisely the problem I have I guess. I haven't been able to prove that there is no natural between n and n+1 either. I can do it for special cases but not for all n..

Comment: @ Horta Be     You can start to show that there is no $ 
p\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ 0<p<1 $. You can prove this by showing the set $ \{0\}\cup\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x\geq 1\} $ is inductive. With that you can prove your base case. The induction step should be easier to do. By this way you have shown there is no natural number between $ n $ and $ n+1 $.